# Install CA - Not trusted certificate - Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I am trying to install a chain certificate from Entrust on a red hat server 7.5 that uses `apache 2.4.6`. Following some articles I found, I did the following:
 Edited `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` file in order to include

**Server Certificate**
`SSLCertificateFile /path/to/file`

**Server Private Key**
`SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/file`

**Certificate Authority(CA)**
`SSLCACertificateFile /path/to/file`

Although site works with https and browser understands the certificate as valid, 
How can I know if the certificate installed successfully? Browser indicates that part of the site is not trusted because of images. Should I do something else with `.cer` and `.pem` files from Entrust? How can I understand if the `chain certificate` is installed as intended?

Comment: A certificate from a CA would not be self signed. Did you edit the correct vhost? Did you restart/reload apache after making the changes?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider you are right I edited the original post because I was looking at another IP

Comment: `Browser indicates that part of the site is not trusted because of images`. Open an image directly and see what's the matter. Either it's loaded from a different server with an invalid certificate or they are loaded over http.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider yes indeed some images are loaded from a different server via http. Is there a way to validate that the `chain certificate` is installed correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to verify the certificates.

1. Go to SSL Labs and run their SSL Server Test. Wait a bit and check the results.
2. Use openssl command line as follows.

Replace HOSTNAME with your actual host name. This assumes you have a valid root certificate chain configured into openssl as well.

```
openssl s_client -connect HOSTNAME:443
```

Then look for the chain in the output, something like this:

```
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=HOSTNAME
   i:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
 1 s:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
   i:/O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
```

and at the very bottom:

```
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```